# How do I set Nautilus to use same window on double click?

Tags: nautilus, directory, filemanager

How do I set Nautilus to use same window on double click when browsing folders?  This would be similar to how windows works.   Right now, my Nautilus opens a new window of nautilus if i double click a folder.   To use the same window I have to remember to nicely click the little arrow icon to expand the folder.

So, is the default behavior changeable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following

Go to '**Edit**' -> '**Preferences**' -> '**Behaviour**'

Uncheck **Open each folder in a new window**

[image]

Comment: :) great minds think alike ...

Comment: That answer was really close but it gave me the hint I needed.  On my disto of CentOS 6.2 I needed to check the box that says "Always open in browser windows."

Comment: + I needed to restart the application to have the setting take effect.

Comment: "Always open in browser windows" wording is less clear than the old wording.  I had seen this option but assumed it wasn't what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

*Edit » Preferences » Behaviour » Open each folder in its own window*

[image: prefs]